# Compiled program stops at first "for" loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, execution

I have a problem. I did a couple of tests and figured out that my program stops right after the first for loop. i have no idea why. I had a smaller program before ,which was reading and writing a file, and it worked just fine. The program compiles and text.txt file is located in the right place.

I am using Bluej. Need any other details? Please ask.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.*;

public class fileStreamTest{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        float averageprice;
        float[] prevDataArray= new float[22];
        float[][] currentDataArray = new float[21][];
        float[] futureData= new float[7];

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("start");

        if (true)//prevDataArray[1]!=7
        {
            for (int xx = 0; xx == 20; xx++)
            {
                int n = 0;
                float input = 0;
                double q1, q3;

                //input data 
                System.out.println("Input data, input 0.00407 to finish.");
                while(input!=0.00407)
                {
                    if (input == 0)
                        input = keyboard.nextFloat();
                    currentDataArray[xx][n] = input;
                    input = keyboard.nextFloat();
                    n++;
                }

                //delete outliers
                n = 0; 

                if((int)(currentDataArray.length/2) == currentDataArray.length/2)
                {
                    if((int)((currentDataArray.length-currentDataArray.length/2)/2) == currentDataArray.length/4)
                    {
                        q1 = (currentDataArray[xx][currentDataArray.length/4]+currentDataArray[xx][currentDataArray.length/4+1])/2;
                        q3 = (currentDataArray[xx][3*currentDataArray.length/4]+currentDataArray[xx][3*currentDataArray.length/4+1])/2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        q1 = currentDataArray[xx][(int)(currentDataArray.length/4) + 1];
                        q3 = currentDataArray[xx][(int)(3*currentDataArray.length/4) + 1];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if((int)((int)(currentDataArray.length/2)/2) == (int)(currentDataArray.length/2)/2)
                    {
                        q1 = (currentDataArray[xx][(int)(currentDataArray.length/2)/2] +  currentDataArray[xx][(int)(currentDataArray.length/2)/2 + 1])/2;
                        q3 = (currentDataArray[xx][3*(int)(currentDataArray.length/2)/2+1] + currentDataArray[xx][3*(int)(currentDataArray.length/2)/2 + 2])/2;
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        q1 = currentDataArray[xx][(int)((int)(currentDataArray.length/2)/2) + 1];
                        q3 = currentDataArray[xx][(int)(3*(int)(currentDataArray.length/2)/2)+ 1];
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("q1 = " + q1 + "/n" + ",q3 = " + q3);
                float sum = 0;
                n = 0;
                while(n!=currentDataArray.length)
                {
                    if((currentDataArray[xx][n] >= q1) && (currentDataArray[xx][n] <= q3))
                    {
                        sum += currentDataArray[xx][n];
                        n++;   
                    }
                }
                //finding average price
                averageprice = sum/n;
                System.out.println(" Average price = " + averageprice);
                //write currentDataFile
                try{
                    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("C:/test.txt");
                    for(int x=0; x < currentDataArray[xx].length ; x++){
                        os.write( (byte)currentDataArray[xx][x] ); // writes the bytes
                    }
                    os.close();
                }catch(IOException e){
                    System.out.print("Exception");
                } 
            }
            prevDataArray[0]++;
        }
        else
        {
            //drawbg
            //drawList
            //createfuturedata(avgdev)
            //drawPred(futuredata)
            //updateavgdev
            System.out.println("test");
            prevDataArray[0] = 1;
        }

        //InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:/test.txt");
        //int size = is.available();

        //  for(int i=0; i< size; i++){
        //     System.out.print((double)is.read() + "  ");
        // }
        //  is.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly before posting. You have a preview just below the location where you type, there you can see how your code looks like.

Comment: The output of the program is :
start


Next thing that should be displayed in the console is: 
Input data...

But it doesn't do that.

Comment: Please read how the for loops work first!

Answer (score 6):

Haven't gone through your whole code, but the problem is certainly in your condition.

```
for (int xx = 0; xx == 20; xx++)
```

This loop should really be: -

```
for (int xx = 0; xx <= 20; xx++)
```

Else, it will not even run once.

Also, your array: -

```
float[][] currentDataArray = new float[21][];
```

Requires a size for the number of columns, else you will get a `NPE` when you access it in the line:

```
currentDataArray[xx][n] = input;
```